# Working with annotation processors in Eclipse 4.6 Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

I am maintaining a Java 7 web project that uses [multiline annotation](http://www.adrianwalker.org/2011/12/java-multiline-string.html) to store certain constants.

I could configure Eclipse fine when I was using Mars, so I could launch Tomcat with that application deployed and it worked like a charm...

Until I upgraded!
Now no annotation processing is done despite the [configuration](https://github.com/benelog/multiline/wiki/Non-Maven-Java-project-with-Eclipse).

I have found that this problem is due to a **feature** of Eclipse 4.6, as documented [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.6.html#mozTocId606104)

> Java 6 annotation processors are supported in the batch compiler and in the IDE. By design, Java 6 processors are only executed during a build, not while editing. (bug 188558)

The linked [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=188558) says, in brief, that annotation processing has been removed from Eclipse's incremental compilation (perhaps the `Build automatically`???) for legitimate reasons. And in fact when I compile my project in CI server using Ant, annotations get processed as usual.

But I can't run my project anymore in Eclipse. It fully depends on the correct processing of the Multiline annotation.

*So far, I have tried* to disable the `Build Automatically` flag and manually build the project. **No result**.

*I also tried* to go to `Java Compiler -> Annotation processing -> Factory Path`, select the `multiline-string` jar, go to `Advanced` properties and uncheck `Run this container's processors in batch mode`, despite the checkbox is counterintuitive (I mean, it should be named "Run in incremental mode" and unchecked by default, according to the above mentioned bug)

The application is a web application, so on every attempt I try to deploy it to local Tomcat.

What do you think I can do about it?

Comment: Turn to the eclipse forums/community? I think this is so special that chances of getting a good answer here aren't too big. Better talk to the people that own that product.

Comment: Is there a solution for this question?

Comment: Have  you got the solution for your problem?

Comment: I killed the annotation processing facility by loading classpath resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. The [multiline annotation](http://www.adrianwalker.org/2011/12/java-multiline-string.html) you are using only supports up to Java version 1.6. (For instance, `MultilineProcessor` specifies `@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)`, and the recommended pom settings specify `source` and `target` values of `1.6`.) If your package is building with a [JDK Compliance Level](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/jdk_compliance) greater than 1.6, this is probably why the annotations are being ignored.
2. Instead of using that annotation, you could just hard-code the multiline strings to your string variables. It would make your code less readable, but builds will be faster.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We chose not to hardcode the strings (HTML templates) for readability issues, but eventually I decided to switch from multiline annotation to using Classpath resource loading, thus storing the templates into formatted and readable files.

Comment: As a reminder, if you think my answer deserves to earn the bounty, you need to award it to me soon; if not, no problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: You should have mentioned @VolkerK :-)

Comment: I did not open the bounty. User VolkerK did. So if you comment the answer then I get the notification, but I can only grant you the accepted flag, not the bounty. Though I already solved my problem, your answer doesn't provide a real `answer` to my problem so I am not currently eager to accept it ;-) no offense

Comment: Ah. It did not occur to me to check if someone else had set the bounty. Seems like the person who sets a bounty should also get notifications automatically, since that person kind of "adopts" the question and really, really wants to know the answer.

Comment: Great to know, I was missing this one

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I totally forgot about this one and didn't log in for a couple of days.... is it "fixable"? (thought the bounty automagically goes to the answer with the most votes)